# Instagram API data not matching Instgram Insights data

Tags: instagram-api

Have you faced an issue where Instagram API is returning different data than it's showing in Instagram Insights?

This is seems to be the problem just for boosted posts. We get one set of numbers from the API, and then different ones are displayed in actual IG Insights. And the differences are pretty big. Anybody had a chance to dig deeper?

Comment: Which kind of data in Instagram Insights? Could you give a couple of examples where the data didn't match?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Post impressions as an example. For a specific IG post, API returns 1850, while in IG Insights impressions for the post shows 32449. The post was boosted. Post likes another example  - API returns 69 for the specific post, IG Insights show 190.

Answer (score 0):

As you already assumed: it has something to do with boosted posts.

The Instagram Graph API does not include ads-driven data while the insights in the Instagram App do.

As the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) states:

> Fields that return aggregated values will not include ads-driven data.
>   For example, comments_count will count comments on a photo, but not
>   comments on ads that contain that photo.

Comment: Actually in the documentation Reach is defined as Total number of times the Business User's media objects (i.e. posts, stories and promotions) have been uniquely viewed. Includes ad activity generated through the API, Facebook ads interfaces, and the Promote feature. Looks like this one has paid data included, but the numbers still don't make sense.

Comment: When you speak about the "actual IG Insights" you mean the insights that the user can see directly in his own IG account - right? What kind of API are you using? The [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) or the [Instagram API platform](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Comment: Yes, correct, insights that user can see on his own IG account. Using Instagram Graph API.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) states for likes and comments: "Fields that return aggregated values will not include ads-driven data. For example, comments_count will count comments on a photo, but not comments on ads that contain that photo."

It's the same with the insights of the Graph API.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that makes sense for likes, etc. I know it's just reach and impressions  that include 'paid' data. But I checked own posts even that were not boosted - what I see in IG app and what I get from the API is still different.